# Определение наведения на блок под блоком JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача обнаружить, если мышь пройдет над блоком, который располагается под другим блоком.

Есть 2 блока

```css
.front{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  opacity: .2;
  background: blue;
}

.back{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
```

Обычный `mouseenter`, естественно, не сработает:

```
$('.back').mouseenter(()=>{console.log('+');});
```

Блок-клон нижнего с `z-index` не предлагайте, до такого и сам догадался, но это возбудит много лишнего html-кода, чего делать не хочется. Должно быть что-то поумнее...

Конструктор: https://jsfiddle.net/few1h534/1/

Comment: А сколько всего будет блоков? Размер и положение блоков может меняться относительно друг друга или везде размеры заданы строго пикселями? + В таком виде не очевидно, почему нельзя изначально заднему блоку дать больший z-index. Если дело в цвете, полупрозрачный фон всё еще можно натянуть на него через ::after.

Comment: Я делаю кастомный курсор, через div. Соответственно, он всегда перекрывает основной курсор. А мне нужно определять наводится ли реальный курсор на область под кастомным. А z-index юзать не хочу так как для каждой активной кнопочки-ссолочки нужно будет создавать прозрачный блок над ней с z-index больше, чем у кастомного курсора. Вот так. (Пример дал более общий, чтобы сразу была понятна суть того, что мне нужно без лишнего шума)

Comment: Может такое подойдет https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/

Comment: Не:/ Курсор должен быть над контентом и на JS/JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно решить через свойство css [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```js
$('.back').mouseenter(()=>{console.log('+');});
```

```css
.front{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  opacity: .2;
  background: blue;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.back{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back"></div>
<div class="front"></div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!